Replacing brake light bulb for VW Passat B8
Need some help on how to replace the outer tail light brake light bulb.
I know how to disconnect and take out the outer tail light unit on my VW Passat Wagon B8, but no idea how to get ot the bulbs. The tail light unit seems a solid unit with no access to the bulbs? I did see five little screws on the back, which I removed, but it does not seem to separate the back from the outer glass to get to the bulbs.
Need some advice here please.
Thanks
